# Extract alternate items from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This feature extraction function:

```
def extract_topological_features(diagrams):
    metrics = ['bottleneck', 'wasserstein', 'landscape', 'betti', 'heat']
    new_features = []
    for metric in metrics:
        amplitude = Amplitude(metric=metric)
        new_features.append(amplitude.fit_transform(diagrams))
        print ('METRIC',metric, amplitude.fit_transform(diagrams).shape)
    new_features = np.concatenate(new_features, axis=1)
    print(new_features, new_features.shape)
    return new_features
```

concatenates my metric features two by two, like so:

```
METRIC bottleneck (3800, 2)
METRIC wasserstein (3800, 2)
METRIC landscape (3800, 2)
METRIC betti (3800, 2)
METRIC heat (3800, 2)
```

and returns full `top_features_train` as an array of features:

```
[[13.13536167  2.21798706 62.73506497 ... 28.64523826 49.43840149
  24.14059374]
 [10.58997917  2.25540924 64.28554504 ... 27.29296562 52.30892719
  24.14042549]
 [10.95345402  2.33446693 63.02889825 ... 19.73039083 53.32755854
  18.64884726]
 ...
 [ 8.14567852  2.04195976 50.25086417 ... 20.61077299 55.02994706
  24.14057505]
 [12.1652956   3.34038877 67.74560592 ... 16.31369624 49.43836393
  21.2406822 ]
 [ 8.77981567  1.87569046 52.18463031 ... 23.58512155 58.15368011
  24.33486122]]
```

with shape:

```
(3800, 10)
```

---

Now I'd like to extract only the first array `(3800, 1)` (not changing the function) for each metric feature from full `top_features_train`, and end up with an array of shape `(3800, 5)`, one for each metric.

How do I do this, keeping track of each feature name?

Comment: if you do not want to change the function, then you can get alternating indexes from the `top_features_trains`. `top_features_train[:,np.array([0,2,4,6])]`. I hope I understood your question clearly?

Comment: I have the same confusion. This should be as simple as ```top_features_train[:,::2]```.